ESXi nonexisting mac-address
I recently installed NAC system in my company and on interface of management switch connected to esxi host i found mac address i cant find anywhere inside. Mac-address is recognized as VMware vendor. None of VM created inside has it, none of physical nic as well. Does esxi has any other element like vswitch with its own mac address ? how to check it ?. i already tried:
in esxi cli: vim-cmd hostsvc/net/info | grep "mac ="
via powershell: get-vm | Get-NetworkAdapter | Select-Object Parent,MacAddress

still cant find this mac - but i see its active on my switch mac address table on interface connected to esxi host.

Yes, VMkernel NICs also use the VMware MAC address range. I was unable to find the MAC addresses in the Web UI of the ESXi itself, but you can list them via the SSH console:
esxcli network ip interface list

or via PowerCLI:
Get-VMHost | Get-VMHostNetwork | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VirtualNic

If your ESXi is connected to a vCenter instance you can also get the information there.


still its not this. I made test. deleted vSwitch connectet to physical switch. Cleared mac address table from physical sw - no mac on interface. Than created only vSwitch - and mac address showed.  So vSwitch on its own has mac ( probably used for beacon packets and so on) but there is no command to list it

Whats more interesting - if you connect multiple physical adapters(nic) to one vswitch - it will generate multiple mac addreses for itself.
